# How to add bottom border for a UIImageView in ios (objective c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is by far what I have done, but when I run this code all the borders are formed. I need to get only the bottom border. Please help. The question I have asked is for UIImage View and not UITextField.

```
    CGFloat borderWidth = 1;
    CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
    [self.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [self.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
    self.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - borderWidth, 
        self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    [self.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
```

Comment: You should set the border width and color to the layer `bottomBorder`.

Comment: change this `self.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - borderWidth, 
        self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);` into `self.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - borderWidth, 
        self.frame.size.width, borderWidth);`

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Vishnu Prasannan,

You only need to update your code as mention below:

```
CGFloat borderWidth = 1;
CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
[bottomBorder setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - borderWidth, self.frame.size.width, borderWidth);
[self.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
```

It will work. Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @MinuMaster but the code didn't work its not showing any borders.